# How to convert string value to DateTimeIndex for pandas range selection using between?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I have a pandas read excel method from where I get a dataframe and the parse_dates parameter is false by default. For visualization with Dash, there are two drop downs for start time and end time and I need to filter the dataframe within this time range based on the value selected in the drop down, but somehow I am stuck here and it gives an exception

> "TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex"

```
df = pd.read_excel(datasource)

html.Div([
        html.Label("Please select a day", style={'textAlign': "center"}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='daydropdown',
            options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dropdownDate],
            multi=False
        ),
        html.Label("Please select a start time", style={'textAlign': "center"}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='starttimedropdown',
            options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dropdownStartTime],
            multi=False
        ),
        html.Label("Please select an end time", style={'textAlign': "center"}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='endtimedropdown',
            options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dropdownEndTime],
            multi=False
        ),
])


@app.callback(
    Output('availability graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('daydropdown', 'value'),
     Input('starttimedropdown', 'value'),
     Input('endtimedropdown', 'value'),
     Input('vehicletype', 'value')]
)
def update_graph(selectedday, selectedstarttime, selectedendtime, selectedvehicletype):
    # get all the parking spaces for the selected day and for the selected vehicle type
    df1 = df[(df["Datum"] == selectedday) & (df["Klassifikation"] == selectedvehicletype)]
    # filter parking spaces by the time range selected
    start = pd.to_datetime(selectedstarttime)
    end = pd.to_datetime(selectedendtime)
    df2 = df1[df1['Uhrzeit'].between_time(start, end)]
```

I expect the df2 to be filtered according to the selected start and end time, but the exception is thrown in this line, `df2 = df1[df1['Uhrzeit'].between_time(start, end)]`

The format of the selected time is `HH:MM:SS`

Comment: Can you post a sample of your `df`? You need to get the index on this to be a datetime index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format for `Uhrzeit` is not a datetime but just an object (it misses the date). Even so formatting the time strings `selectedstarttime` and `selectedendtime` is only possible because pandas put the date of today in front of the time section:

`pd.to_datetime('08:22:22') = Timestamp('2019-08-06 08:22:22')`

If you want to use `between_time` make sure that the object you are checking is a datetime object. The arguments in the function can be written as HH:MM, and dont have to be datetime:

`df2['Urhzeit'].between_time('0:15', '0:45')`